# Implement a function as a member of utility

Tags: function, member, utility

Let's say I have a class with objects that are populated in regards to another member in that class.

Let's use the example of a library. If I have a database of books, and my class is called User. User has a member called name. User has an object (say a list) that contains all borrowed books from the library. Where should the function that populates the member list "booksBorrowed" with books from the member object "name"

Do I implement a helper function outside the class called getBooks( ... ) which accepts a User Class Type, or should I implement the function as a member to the Class? Obviously if I implement as a utility function, I would obviously need to provide wrapper for populating the list object inside the user class.

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I'd think hard before choosing to have a member list "booksBorrowed" in User at all because it would be hard to ensure that the Library and all Users were always consistent, e.g. to ensure that the same book does not appear at the same time on the "booksBorrowed" lists of more than one User.

My inclination would be to have a "bookList" in the Library that contains all the books (whether borrowed or not), and a "location" field in each Book object that is either a reference to a particular User or to the Library (or null in the latter case, perhaps). Since the "location" field can only ever have one value, it would then be impossible for a book to be in two locations at once.

At any given time, one could then then obtain a "booksBorrowed" list for a given User by calling a member function in Library that returns such a list for a given User.

If that caused efficiency concerns because the "booksBorrowed" member function might have to search through millions of books to create the list each time, one could optimise by having Library update a "booksBorrowed" list in the Library object for each user, each time a book is borrowed or returned. However, that wouldn't change the user interface that I've outlined so I'd be inclined not to do this optimisation until performance considerations indicated that it was needed.